# How to send a command in a Process with C++?

Tags: c++, windows, c++11, c++17

I have two application, first app is create a Process:

```
 if( !CreateProcess( myexe,   // No module name (use command line)
    NULL,        // Command line
    NULL,           // Process handle not inheritable
    NULL,           // Thread handle not inheritable
    FALSE,          // Set handle inheritance to FALSE
    0,              // No creation flags
    NULL,           // Use parent's environment block
    NULL,           // Use parent's starting directory 
    &si,            // Pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
    &pi )           // Pointer to PROCESS_INFORMATION structure
)
```

process name is myexe.exe:

myexe   waiting a input,

```
 #include <iostream>
using namespace std; 
int main()
{
    string value;

    while(true){
      cin>>value;
    }
}
```

How to send input value on cpp?

Comment: Actually i want an answer for windows

Answer (score 0):

You need to create pipe, assing handles to STARTUPINFO structure (si) and write data to pipe after you create process.

Look at this example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/creating-a-child-process-with-redirected-input-and-output